# Show $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group: Question on proving closure

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, automorphism-group

This is a very narrow question I haven't been able to find answered elsewhere.

> Given a group $G$, I want to prove that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$ is a group.

All of the steps make sense to me, but I'm wondering about proving closure. For any $f,g \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, so I need to prove both that $f \circ g$ and $g \circ f$ are elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$? What qualifies as closure in this case?

When I normally prove that a group is closed, I take arbitrary $a,b$ and prove that $ab \in G$. Even then I'm questioning why I don't need that $ba$ is also an element of $G$. Is this drawing on symmetry of the labels?

Comment: Yes, you need to show $f\circ g$ is an automorphism too if $f$ and $g$ are. Yes, showing $ab\in G$ for all $a,b\in G$ is sufficient by symmetry of labels.

Answer (score 4):

Automorphisms are bijections and the composition of bijections is bijections.

So we only need to show compatibility with the group operation.

If $x,y \in G$, $f,g \in {\rm Aut}(G)$,

$$\begin{align}
(f\circ g)(xy) &= f(g(xy)) \\
&= f(g(x)g(y)) \\
&= f(g(x))(f(g(y)) \\
&= (f\circ g)(x)(f\circ g)(y).
\end{align}$$

So we can see $f\circ g$ is a bijection from $G$ to itself and respects the group operation, hence an automorphism.